# Laravel Dingo/Api Doctrine

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine, dingo-api

- I use Laravel with Dingo/Api to build a RESTful API (https://github.com/dingo/api)
- I use Doctrine2 instead of Eloquent ORM (https://github.com/laravel-doctrine/orm)
- The entities are generated from XML-Annotations

I'm in struggle because Dingo seems to transform only Eloquent collections and objects. I could solve returning the collection with the method Collection::make().

**But how is it possible to return a single user object?** (see method getUser())

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Entities\User;
use App\Transformer\UserTransformer;
use Dingo\Api\Http\Response;
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;

class UsersController extends Controller
{
    use Helpers;

    protected $em;

    /**
     * UsersController constructor.
     * @param $em
     */
    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function getUser($id)
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(array('id' => $id));

        return $user;
    }


    public function getUsers()
    {
        $user = $this->em->getRepository(User::class)->findAll();

        return $this->response->collection(Collection::make($user), new UserTransformer);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily I have found a working solution now. I want to share this and hope to be able to help other people:

```
    return $this->response->item($user, new UserTransformer());
```